# Python pandas: store Series subclass as a DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a `DataFrame` that contains a number of *different* `Series` subclasses I've defined. It seems that the subclass is stripped from the `Series` when assigned to a `DataFrame`, however.

Here's a toy example to illustrate the problem:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> class SeriesSubclass(pd.Series):
...     @property
...     def _constructor(self):
...         return SeriesSubclass
...     def times_two(self):
...     """Method I need in this subclass."""
...         return self * 2
...
>>> subclass = SeriesSubclass([7, 8, 9])
>>> type(subclass)                   # fine
<class '__main__.SeriesSubclass'>
>>> subclass.times_two()             # fine
0    14
1    16
2    18
dtype: int64
>>>
>>> data = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], columns=list('ABC'))
>>> data['D'] = subclass
>>> type(data['D'])                  # not good
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
>>> data['D'].times_two()            # not good
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'times_two'
```

I've seen this issue may have been raised previously [#1713](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/1713), but I can't discern the actual solution. Being such a huge library, its difficult to follow the various PRs, doc versions, etc. And the subclassing mechanics don't seem that well described as far as I can tell ([this seems to be it](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/internals.html)).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're out of luck unless you also define your own `pd.DataFrame` subclass.  And that would be an even more daunting task.

consider this example

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])
s.random_attribute = 'hello!'
print(s.random_attribute)

df['A'] = s
print(df.A.random_attribute)

hello!
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-273-e0031d933193> in <module>()
      5 
      6 df['A'] = s
----> 7 print(df.A.random_attribute)

//anaconda/envs/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   2742             if name in self._info_axis:
   2743                 return self[name]
-> 2744             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   2745 
   2746     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'random_attribute'
```

`df.A` is not `s`.  `df.A` gets constructed from `s` and ignores what type it is.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of anyone with a similar need: I think the best solution is to define a subclass of `DataFrame` and intervene with the `__getitem__` logic.

My original question was based on the assumption that a `DataFrame` is implemented as a container, which fundamentally it isn't. It's more dynamic, e.g...

```
>>> from pandas import Series, DataFrame
>>> s = Series([1, 2, 3, 4], name='x')
>>> df = DataFrame(s)
>>> s is df.x
False
```

Therefore, in order to retrieve columns as subclasses of `Series`, you'll need to tinker with `__getitem__`.

I have implemented this in my own package, which might serve as an example: https://github.com/jmackie4/activityio/blob/master/activityio/_util/types.py

I'd be keen to hear from anyone with a more elegant solution though!